# Sierpinski's generalization of Riemann's rearrangement theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

I recall that Riemann's theorem on conditionnaly convergent series states that if a series converges conditionnaly, then you can rearrange the sequence so that the new series converges to whatever real number you choose, or diverges.

I'm interested in Sierpinski's generalization :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Sierpi.C5.84ski_theorem

Several results are stated in this paragraph and I'd like to be sure that I understand them properly. The Wikipedia article gives references but I couldn't find them and I think they're in Polish, which I don't understand.

1. > all the indexes of the terms of the series may be rearranged

Does this mean that we can restrict ourselves to permutations with no fixed point?

2. > Sierpiński proved that is sufficient to rearrange only some strictly positive terms or only some strictly negative terms.

So we can always choose a permutation such that every positive (resp. negative) term keeps its rank, except finitely many, and we can do what we want with negative (resp. positive) terms?

3. > it is proved that is sufficient to rearrange only the indexes in the ideal of sets of asymptotic density zero

I don't understand this. I know what an ideal is in the context of ring theory, but what is an ideal of sets of asymptotic density zero?

Comment: [This](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/the-theorems-of-riemann-and-sierpinski-on-rearrangement-of-series/) looks like it contains a formal statement of at least some of Sierpiński, along with a proof. Given the titles of the papers, I'd expect them to be in French.

Comment: I think that I've read somewhere that only the title is in French, and the rest in Polish. If they're in French I'd like to find them (I'm French). Thank you for you link, it'll help!

Comment: At least one of them is available, in French, [here](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Sierpinski%20Oeuvres%20Choisies%20I.pdf), in a selection of his works. It seems that some people have already studied and extended his results, so you can probably find them exposited elsewhere as well, given what a Google search turned up when I tried it.

Comment: Yes thank you this is indeed in French. This answers my second question. For those interested, it's page 115 of the pdf.